# Pods unable to run on IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

So I've been using a lot of third party libraries recently via cocoapods. But upon running the '.xcworkspace' project on a device, errors indicate that no pods exist. For a more specific example, when I use firebase, the back end service only retrieves and saves data through a build in simulator but not on the device.

Another example is when I use SVProgressHUD. Despite the pod files and pod projects existing, running the project on a device displays the error: "No modules 'SVProgressHUD'" on the import line. Once again, simulator works perfectly.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase, you still need to login, even if you allow anonymous users.  On the simulator, you don't need to following code, but on physical devices, you do.

```
var ref: Firebase! // 1
ref = Firebase(url: "\(FIREBASE)") // 2
ref.authAnonymouslyWithCompletionBlock { (error, authData) in // 1
   if error != nil { print(error.description); return } // 2

   // The rest of your code     
}
```